# Finding the correct combination in a 2D array after finding the first digit

Tags: java, arrays, search, multidimensional-array

I'm having hard time coding this ... I want to find a certain combination of numbers in a 2D grid. This combination is already known and is stored in an ArrayList. The catch is that the combination can be completed from ANY of the 8 cardinal directions (stored as ints from 0 to 7) like a word search puzzle. I'm trying to find that direction but honestly I'm not sure where to go from here ...

```
[...] //This is only a part of the bigger code I'm working on

for (i = 0; i < grid.length; ++i){
    for (j = 0; j < grid[i].length; ++j){
        if (grid[i][j] == digits.get(0){   //Here I find the 1st digit of my number


        }
    }
}
```

Keep in mind that the number entered can be of ANY length and that the direction is only returned IF I get the whole number. I'm so lost literally any advice is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Try first encoding a class that can traverse table in given direction. For example, top-bottom or bottom-top. Then you can enumerate all eight possible directions as that traverser, and for each traverser check for your sequence.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (i = 0; i < grid.length; ++i){
for (j = 0; j < grid[i].length; ++j){
    int gridItemIndex = digits.indexOf( grid[i][j] )
    {
        if( gridItemIndex != -1 )
        {
             // now you are sure grid[i][j] IS IN LIST
             // gridItemIndex tells THE INDEX NUMBER OF grid[i][j] in ArrayList(digits)
        }
    }
}
```

I hope this gets to close to what you are trying to say??

```
int gridItemIndex = digits.indexOf( grid[i][j] )
{
    if( gridItemIndex != -1 )
    {
         // now you are sure grid[i][j] IS IN LIST
         // gridItemIndex tells THE INDEX NUMBER OF grid[i][j] in ArrayList(digits)
    }
}
```

Deals with the case where you are trying to locate the existence and index number of grid[i][j] in digits ArrayList, And please don't -vefy my answer before not even discussing why and the end result of your expected combination is a bit blurry still, would be glad to help

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem here is that you don't see the bigger picture. The below is your starting point, cleaned up a bit.
Now what I would do is write a method that checks the table in every direction for the length of your combination. Checking for north is basically doing grid[startingX][startingY--]. If you apply that logic to every direction and account for 'out of bounds'-errors, you will solve it in no time.

```
//2D array
    int[][] grid = new int[25][25];
    //Your combination
    List<Integer> combination = new ArrayList<>();

    //Loop over the 2D array to find your starting point
    for (int i = 0; i<25; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j<25; j++) {

            if (grid[i][j] == combination.get(0)) { //If we find the first element of your combination
                //Check in all cardinal directions
                checkDirections(i, j);
            }
        }
    }
```